# Record audio in AMR file format

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I wan to record audio in AMR file format. I am currently using bellow code to record audio:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Sample.3gp";

myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

But it generates .3gp file. How can I get .amr file?
**Changing outputfile to Sample.amr works. But is it a correct way?** Please help

EDIT
**ITS SOLVED NOW**

It was my Silly Mistake: I used `myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);`

It should be-

```
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

So bellow code is working for Recording in AMR format:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Sample.amr";

    myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to [android OutputFormat document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html)
Try below code:

```
    Log.i(TAG,"Record start");
    String outputFile;
    MediaRecorder myRecorder;
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Sample.amr";
    Log.i(TAG,"file name: " + outputFile);

    myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    try {
        myRecorder.prepare();
        myRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myRecorder.stop();
    myRecorder.release();
    Log.i(TAG,"Record finished");
```

Key points:

1. Out file name use ".amr" suffix. Output format use OutputFormat.AMR_NB parameter.
2. Encorder use AudioEncoder.AMR_NB
   parameter.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already tried this. It force closes app when we start recording with error:  **Start failed -22** java.lang.RuntimeException: Start Failed

Comment: Did you call prepare firstly, then call start. it's helpful if you can share the the whole file.

Comment: Check my edited version, it works on moto g device. what's your device? maybe device issue.

Comment: Yes I am calling prepare first and then Start. I have rooted Samsung Galaxy Ace(OS Cyanogen mod 7 - 2.3.7). Is it because its rooted? I will test on other devices and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Beetlej  Thanks! It is working now. It was my Silly mistake. I used `myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);`

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. Only one thing - Volume of recorded file is Very Low. Any work around for that?